# Суммировать value при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто разбирается

Есть поле `<input value="50">`

И есть 3 отдельных элемента

```
<div class="price_1">1</div><button id="price_1">Добавить</button>
<div class="price_2">2</div><button id="price_2">Добавить</button>
<div class="price_3">3</div><button id="price_3">Добавить</button>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любую кнопку button, в поле `<input value="50">` добавлялась цена, написанная в блоках price_1, price_2, price_3

И если нажать кнопку повторно - убиралась

```js
        function addition1() {
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
            var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value);
            if (isNaN(a)==true) a=0;
            if (isNaN(b)==true) b=0;
 
            var s = a + b;
            
            var obj=document.getElementById("result");
            obj.value=s;
        }

        function addition2() {
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
            var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('c').value);
            if (isNaN(a)==true) a=0;
            if (isNaN(c)==true) b=0;
 
            var s = a + c;
            
            var obj=document.getElementById("result");
            obj.value=s;
        }

        function addition3() {
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
            var d = parseInt(document.getElementById('d').value);
            if (isNaN(a)==true) a=0;
            if (isNaN(b)==true) b=0;
 
            var s = a + d;
            
            var obj=document.getElementById("result");
            obj.value=s;
        }
```

```html
    <input id="b" type="text" value="10"> <input type="button" value="a+b" onclick="addition1();"><br>
    <input id="c" type="text" value="20"> <input type="button" value="a+c" onclick="addition2();"><br>
    <input id="d" type="text" value="30"> <input type="button" value="a+d" onclick="addition3();"><br>

    <form>
        <input id="a" type="text" value="100">
        <input id="result" value="">
    </form>
```

Comment: Попытайтесь сами. Если не будет получаться - обращайтесь

Comment: @Alexander Chernin В том то и дело, что уже 2 дня пытаюсь)

Comment: Покажите что (не)получилось. Если тут решат за вас, то как вы сами-то научитесь?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, обновил вопрос с кодом, накрутил тут. Думаю что знающие люди намного проще написали бы, по этому и не скидывал свой вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю правильно понял задачу.

Придётся чутка поправить вёрстку..
Остальное описано в комментариях к коду.

p.s. код на **jQuery**.

```js
let input = $('#total_price');

$('button').on('click', function(){
  let price = parseInt($('.'+$(this).attr('id')).text()), // раз класс "цены" и ид кнопки совпадает, то будем это использовать.
      check = $(this).attr('data-check'), // для проверки, типо "вкл\выкл"
      altText = $(this).attr('data-alt-text'); // будем менять текст на кнопке.

  // изменяем данные кнопки
  $(this) 
    .attr({ 
      'data-check': (check == 1 ? 0 : 1), // заменим "статус" активации
      'data-alt-text': $(this).text() // поменяем местами название кнопки
    })
    .text(altText); // относится к смене названия местами
  
  // дальше меняем цену в инпуте
  let val = parseInt(input.val()); // получаем текущую цену
  input.val(check == 1 ? (val - price) : (val + price)); // есть "добавить", то + к цене, если "убрать", то минус.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="total_price" type="text" value="50" readonly>
<hr>
<div class="price_1">1</div>
<button id="price_1" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
<br>
<div class="price_2">2</div>
<button id="price_2" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
<br>
<div class="price_3">3</div>
<button id="price_3" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
```

---

По поводу ответа **[@Anton Shchyrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1054216/221218)**:

> ..Я состояние храню классом. Бонусом этого - можно еще изменять внешний вид кнопки

Используя атрибут `data-***` тоже можно изменять дизайн кнопки)

```js
let input = $('#total_price');

$('button').on('click', function(){
  let price = parseInt($('.'+$(this).attr('id')).text()),
      check = $(this).attr('data-check'),
      altText = $(this).attr('data-alt-text');

  $(this).attr({'data-check': (check == 1 ? 0 : 1), 'data-alt-text': $(this).text()}).text(altText);
  let val = parseInt(input.val());
  input.val(check == 1 ? (val - price) : (val + price));
});
```

```css
button[data-check] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

button[data-check]:hover {
  opacity: .85;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}

button[data-check="0"] {
  background: green;
}

button[data-check="1"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="total_price" type="text" value="50" readonly>
<hr>
<div class="price_1">1</div>
<button id="price_1" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
<br>
<div class="price_2">2</div>
<button id="price_2" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
<br>
<div class="price_3">3</div>
<button id="price_3" data-check="0" data-alt-text="Убрать">Добавить</button>
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, когда передаю значение <input id="total_price" type="text" value="50" readonly>  на почту, вместо числа получается NaN. Как можно исправить

Answer (score 2):

1. Как при повторном клике убирать значение не придумал :((

```js
let button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');
let d = input.value;
 for(let i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      input.value = event.target.closest('.b').querySelectorAll('.price')[i].innerHTML;
      console.clear();
      console.log( +d + +input.value )
    })    
}
```

```html
<input value="50">
<div class="b">
  <div class="price_1 price" >1</div><button id="price_1">Добавить</button>
  <div class="price_2 price">2</div><button id="price_2">Добавить</button>
  <div class="price_3 price">3</div><button id="price_3">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Распишите новичку, что делает ваш код

Comment: @Alexander Chernin задачи становятся все труднее и труднее ...

Comment: @Alexander Chernin появился новый ответ все еще актуально описывать ?

Comment: В принципе,  если он попросит )

Comment: Мне кажется, ваш код делает не то, что нужно ТС. Ему нужно прибавлять\отнимать значение, а вы его просто меняете.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko изначально этого не было, он (она) после обновила вопрос ...

Comment: Ааа понятно... Но вы ответ дали 20 минут назад, ТС поменял вопрос 30 минут назад :) К тому же и в первой редакции было написано *в поле <input value="50"> добавлялась цена, написанная в блоках price_1, price_2, price_3*

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko ага, придется ответ удалять :((

Comment: А зачем удалять, если можно изменить?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko написал вверху Как при повторном клике убирать значение не придумал :((

Answer (score 2):

Для начала зачем вам три идентичных функции, если можно использовать одну, передавая ей аргументом, что мы нажали.

Далее, вам нужно хранить состояние кнопки (нажата/отжата) и при нажатии определять нужно складывать или вычитать значение. Я состояние храню классом. Бонусом этого - можно еще изменять внешний вид кнопки

```js
function addition(btn) {
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  var a = parseInt(res.value);
  var b = parseInt(btn.previousElementSibling.value);
  if (isNaN(a) === true) {
    a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
    if (isNaN(a) === true)
      a = 0;
  }
  if (isNaN(b) === true) b = 0;

  res.value = (btn.classList.contains('pressed')) ? a - b : a + b;

  btn.classList.toggle('pressed');
}
```

```css
.pressed {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="b" type="text" value="10"> <input type="button" value="a+b" onclick="addition(this);"><br>
<input id="c" type="text" value="20"> <input type="button" value="a+c" onclick="addition(this);"><br>
<input id="d" type="text" value="30"> <input type="button" value="a+d" onclick="addition(this);"><br>

<form>
  <input id="a" type="text" value="100">
  <input id="result" value="">
</form>
```